# When the program runs it waits for 5 seconds to play music but after that it plays music after every second

Tags: python

The program should wait 5 seconds  every time it plays music.
The code-

```
from pygame import mixer
from time import time
from datetime import datetime


def music(file,stopper):

    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(file)
    mixer.music.play()
   
    while True:
        var=input()
        if var==stopper:
            mixer.music.stop()
            break

def logs(msg):

    with open("logs.txt","a") as f:
        f.write(f"{datetime.now()} {msg}\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    water_t=time()
    eyes_t=time()
    exercise_t=time()
    water_s=5

    while True:
        if time()-water_t>water_s:
            print(time()-water_t)
            print("Enter done to stop the alarm")
            music('water.mp3',"done")
            u_t=water_t 
            logs("Water drank at")
```

Comment: Try to space out code with some newlines to separate logical segments of code (if you don't know how just do it randomly once in a while). Also, put a space around operators as `=`, `+`, `-`, `,`, and such. This helps to space out lines so they read as words in a sentence instead of just a single run-on sentence. This makes your code easier to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did

```
u_t=water_t
```

but `u_t` is used in nowhere other than this.

It should be

```
water_t=time()
```